# SSRS Reports being generated sequentially following a data driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a data driven subscription that generates over 1000 reports.  It's scheduled for 2:00 AM on Monday and the last report is generated close to 5:00 AM.  This isn't a problem except that I have other reports (data driven and plain subscription) that are scheduled for 4:00 AM and while the SQL Agent job and Report Manager shows that they kicked off at 4:00, the report server service log shows that they don't actually generate at that time.  In fact, they generated following the last of the 1000+ reports from 2:00 job.  So, they seem to be running sequentially instead of simultaneously.  Is this normal or something I can control?

I've not changed any of the reportserver.config settings (MaxActiveReqForOneUser and MaxQueueThreads are at default values, 20 and 0).

Should I just stagger these that the quicker reports don't have to wait for the 1000+ reports to complete?